# Parse multipart/form-data file in UTF-8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, cgi

I am parsing a multipart/form input with Python's cgi module:

```
body_file = StringIO.StringIO(self.request.body)
pdict = {'boundary': 'xYzZY'}
httpbody = cgi.parse_multipart(body_file, pdict)
text = self.trim(httpbody['text'])
```

and I want to print some elements of httpbody that are the UTF-8 encoded.
I tried `text.decode('utf-8')` and `unicode(text, encoding='utf-8')`, but nothing seems to work. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
text = self.trim(httpbody['text'])
text.encode('utf-8')
```

I'm assuming the `text` variable is in string, if not sure `str()`. Otherwise, you'll get another error thrown at you.